# How do I reproduce llvm O3 manually?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, llvm

I get the llvm O3 by the command:
`opt -enable-new-pm=0 -S -O3 input.ll -debug-pass=Arguments`

and I get the pass:

```
Pass Arguments:  -tti -tbaa -scoped-noalias-aa -assumption-cache-tracker -targetlibinfo -verify -lower-expect -simplifycfg -domtree -sroa -early-cse
Pass Arguments:  -targetlibinfo -tti -targetpassconfig -tbaa -scoped-noalias-aa -assumption-cache-tracker -profile-summary-info -annotation2metadata -forceattrs -inferattrs -domtree -callsite-splitting -ipsccp -called-value-propagation -globalopt -domtree -mem2reg -deadargelim -domtree -basic-aa -aa -loops -lazy-branch-prob -lazy-block-freq -opt-remark-emitter -instcombine -simplifycfg -basiccg -globals-aa -prune-eh -inline -openmp-opt-cgscc -function-attrs -argpromotion -domtree -sroa -basic-aa -aa -memoryssa -early-cse-memssa -speculative-execution -aa -lazy-value-info -jump-threading -correlated-propagation -simplifycfg -domtree -aggressive-instcombine -basic-aa -aa -loops -lazy-branch-prob -lazy-block-freq -opt-remark-emitter -instcombine -libcalls-shrinkwrap -loops -postdomtree -branch-prob -block-freq -lazy-branch-prob -lazy-block-freq -opt-remark-emitter -pgo-memop-opt -basic-aa -aa -loops -lazy-branch-prob -lazy-block-freq -opt-remark-emitter -tailcallelim -simplifycfg -reassociate -domtree -basic-aa -aa -memoryssa -loops -loop-simplify -lcssa-verification -lcssa -scalar-evolution -lazy-branch-prob -lazy-block-freq -licm -loop-rotate -licm -loop-unswitch -simplifycfg -domtree -basic-aa -aa -loops -lazy-branch-prob -lazy-block-freq -opt-remark-emitter -instcombine -loop-simplify -lcssa-verification -lcssa -scalar-evolution -loop-idiom -indvars -loop-deletion -loop-unroll -sroa -aa -mldst-motion -phi-values -aa -memdep -lazy-branch-prob -lazy-block-freq -opt-remark-emitter -gvn -sccp -demanded-bits -bdce -basic-aa -aa -lazy-branch-prob -lazy-block-freq -opt-remark-emitter -instcombine -lazy-value-info -jump-threading -correlated-propagation -postdomtree -adce -basic-aa -aa -memoryssa -memcpyopt -loops -dse -loop-simplify -lcssa-verification -lcssa -aa -scalar-evolution -lazy-branch-prob -lazy-block-freq -licm -simplifycfg -domtree -basic-aa -aa -loops -lazy-branch-prob -lazy-block-freq -opt-remark-emitter -instcombine -barrier -elim-avail-extern -basiccg -rpo-function-attrs -globalopt -globaldce -basiccg -globals-aa -domtree -float2int -lower-constant-intrinsics -loops -loop-simplify -lcssa-verification -lcssa -basic-aa -aa -scalar-evolution -loop-rotate -loop-accesses -lazy-branch-prob -lazy-block-freq -opt-remark-emitter -loop-distribute -postdomtree -branch-prob -block-freq -scalar-evolution -basic-aa -aa -loop-accesses -demanded-bits -lazy-branch-prob -lazy-block-freq -opt-remark-emitter -inject-tli-mappings -loop-vectorize -loop-simplify -scalar-evolution -aa -loop-accesses -lazy-branch-prob -lazy-block-freq -loop-load-elim -basic-aa -aa -lazy-branch-prob -lazy-block-freq -opt-remark-emitter -instcombine -simplifycfg -domtree -loops -scalar-evolution -basic-aa -aa -demanded-bits -lazy-branch-prob -lazy-block-freq -opt-remark-emitter -inject-tli-mappings -slp-vectorizer -vector-combine -opt-remark-emitter -instcombine -loop-simplify -lcssa-verification -lcssa -scalar-evolution -loop-unroll -lazy-branch-prob -lazy-block-freq -opt-remark-emitter -instcombine -memoryssa -loop-simplify -lcssa-verification -lcssa -scalar-evolution -lazy-branch-prob -lazy-block-freq -licm -opt-remark-emitter -transform-warning -alignment-from-assumptions -strip-dead-prototypes -globaldce -constmerge -cg-profile -domtree -loops -postdomtree -branch-prob -block-freq -loop-simplify -lcssa-verification -lcssa -basic-aa -aa -scalar-evolution -block-freq -loop-sink -lazy-branch-prob -lazy-block-freq -opt-remark-emitter -instsimplify -div-rem-pairs -simplifycfg -annotation-remarks -verify
Pass Arguments:  -domtree
Pass Arguments:  -targetlibinfo -domtree -loops -postdomtree -branch-prob -block-freq
Pass Arguments:  -targetlibinfo -domtree -loops -postdomtree -branch-prob -block-freq
Pass Arguments:  -targetlibinfo -domtree -loops -lazy-branch-prob -lazy-block-freq
```

Now, I use the sequence by these:

```
opt -S -enable-new-pm=0 -tti -tbaa -scoped-noalias-aa -assumption-cache-tracker -targetlibinfo -verify -lower-expect -simplifycfg -domtree -sroa -early-cse file.ll`

opt -S -enable-new-pm=0 -targetlibinfo -tti -targetpassconfig -tbaa -scoped-noalias-aa -assumption-cache-tracker -profile-summary-info -annotation2metadata -forceattrs -inferattrs -domtree -callsite-splitting -ipsccp -called-value-propagation -globalopt -domtree -mem2reg -deadargelim -domtree -basic-aa -aa -loops -lazy-branch-prob -lazy-block-freq -opt-remark-emitter -instcombine -simplifycfg -basiccg -globals-aa -prune-eh -inline -openmp-opt-cgscc -function-attrs -argpromotion -domtree -sroa -basic-aa -aa -memoryssa -early-cse-memssa -speculative-execution -aa -lazy-value-info -jump-threading -correlated-propagation -simplifycfg -domtree -aggressive-instcombine -basic-aa -aa -loops -lazy-branch-prob -lazy-block-freq -opt-remark-emitter -instcombine -libcalls-shrinkwrap -loops -postdomtree -branch-prob -block-freq -lazy-branch-prob -lazy-block-freq -opt-remark-emitter -pgo-memop-opt -basic-aa -aa -loops -lazy-branch-prob -lazy-block-freq -opt-remark-emitter -tailcallelim -simplifycfg -reassociate -domtree -basic-aa -aa -memoryssa -loops -loop-simplify -lcssa-verification -lcssa -scalar-evolution -lazy-branch-prob -lazy-block-freq -licm -loop-rotate -licm -loop-unswitch -simplifycfg -domtree -basic-aa -aa -loops -lazy-branch-prob -lazy-block-freq -opt-remark-emitter -instcombine -loop-simplify -lcssa-verification -lcssa -scalar-evolution -loop-idiom -indvars -loop-deletion -loop-unroll -sroa -aa -mldst-motion -phi-values -aa -memdep -lazy-branch-prob -lazy-block-freq -opt-remark-emitter -gvn -sccp -demanded-bits -bdce -basic-aa -aa -lazy-branch-prob -lazy-block-freq -opt-remark-emitter -instcombine -lazy-value-info -jump-threading -correlated-propagation -postdomtree -adce -basic-aa -aa -memoryssa -memcpyopt -loops -dse -loop-simplify -lcssa-verification -lcssa -aa -scalar-evolution -lazy-branch-prob -lazy-block-freq -licm -simplifycfg -domtree -basic-aa -aa -loops -lazy-branch-prob -lazy-block-freq -opt-remark-emitter -instcombine -barrier -elim-avail-extern -basiccg -rpo-function-attrs -globalopt -globaldce -basiccg -globals-aa -domtree -float2int -lower-constant-intrinsics -loops -loop-simplify -lcssa-verification -lcssa -basic-aa -aa -scalar-evolution -loop-rotate -loop-accesses -lazy-branch-prob -lazy-block-freq -opt-remark-emitter -loop-distribute -postdomtree -branch-prob -block-freq -scalar-evolution -basic-aa -aa -loop-accesses -demanded-bits -lazy-branch-prob -lazy-block-freq -opt-remark-emitter -inject-tli-mappings -loop-vectorize -loop-simplify -scalar-evolution -aa -loop-accesses -lazy-branch-prob -lazy-block-freq -loop-load-elim -basic-aa -aa -lazy-branch-prob -lazy-block-freq -opt-remark-emitter -instcombine -simplifycfg -domtree -loops -scalar-evolution -basic-aa -aa -demanded-bits -lazy-branch-prob -lazy-block-freq -opt-remark-emitter -inject-tli-mappings -slp-vectorizer -vector-combine -opt-remark-emitter -instcombine -loop-simplify -lcssa-verification -lcssa -scalar-evolution -loop-unroll -lazy-branch-prob -lazy-block-freq -opt-remark-emitter -instcombine -memoryssa -loop-simplify -lcssa-verification -lcssa -scalar-evolution -lazy-branch-prob -lazy-block-freq -licm -opt-remark-emitter -transform-warning -alignment-from-assumptions -strip-dead-prototypes -globaldce -constmerge -cg-profile -domtree -loops -postdomtree -branch-prob -block-freq -loop-simplify -lcssa-verification -lcssa -basic-aa -aa -scalar-evolution -block-freq -loop-sink -lazy-branch-prob -lazy-block-freq -opt-remark-emitter -instsimplify -div-rem-pairs -simplifycfg -annotation-remarks -verify file.ll
opt -S -enable-new-pm=0 -targetlibinfo -domtree -loops -postdomtree -branch-prob -block-freq file.ll
opt -S -enable-new-pm=0 -targetlibinfo -domtree -loops -postdomtree -branch-prob -block-freq file.ll
opt -S -enable-new-pm=0 -targetlibinfo -domtree -loops -lazy-branch-prob -lazy-block-freq file.ll
```

But the result of IR **is not the same** as `opt -S -enable-new-pm=0 -O3 file.ll`

I know some of the passes above are analyze passes, but I think there should not be different.

How can I get the IR same as O3 by passing the O3 sequence?

Or are there any other method to do that?